# Failed to post notification on channel “null” Target Api is 27

Tags: java, android, android-studio

After upgrading my app target api to 27  notification is no more working and i get a toast message on android studio emulator:

> Failed to post notification on channel “null”

Here is my notification code:

```
 private void sendNotification(Context context, String sysModel) {
    Intent intentAction = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);

    intentAction.putExtra("sysModel", sysModel);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 1, intentAction, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.changer_ico)
            .setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.service_ready))
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .addAction(R.drawable.ic_key_black_24dp, context.getString(R.string.turn_on), pendingIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(true);

    Notification notification = notificationBuilder.build();

    notificationManager.notify(1903, notification);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you test the code below?

Note that `new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL);` instead of `new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);`

```
private final static String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL = "channel_name";
private final static String CHANNEL_DESCRIPTION = "channel_description";
public final static int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1903;

private void sendNotification(Context context, String sysModel) {

    // Intent
    Intent intentAction = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    intentAction.putExtra("sysModel", sysModel);

    // Pending Intent
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 1, intentAction, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    // Notification Manager
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Service.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    // Create the notification channel if android >= 8
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL, CHANNEL_DESCRIPTION, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }

    // Notification builder.. Note that I added the notification channel on this constructor
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL);
    notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.changer_ico)
    notificationBuilder.setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.service_ready))
    notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
    notificationBuilder.addAction(R.drawable.ic_key_black_24dp, context.getString(R.string.turn_on), pendingIntent)
    notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);

    // Notify
    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

Comment: worked thank you alot just hade to add ; on the following lines :
notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.changer_ico);
    notificationBuilder.setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.service_ready));
    notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    notificationBuilder.addAction(R.drawable.ic_key_black_24dp, context.getString(R.string.turn_on), pendingIntent);

Answer (score 0):

In android O you should dispatch notice like follow:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.changer_ico)
                .setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.service_ready))
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .addAction(R.drawable.ic_key_black_24dp, context.getString(R.string.turn_on), pendingIntent)
                .setAutoCancel(true);

        Notification notification = notificationBuilder.build();
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("1903",
                context.getString(R.string.user_notify), NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        notificationManager.notify(1903, notification);
```

Comment: Did you check notification's permission,and by the way you need uninstall your apk from your device and install it again.

Comment: my current code snippet is posted on my question but please note that i am sending this notification from on bootreciver.java class if this will make any deference.. i am new to android

Comment: As I said you need create a notification channel for your notification in Android O,I didn't see that in your code snippet.

Comment: Yes i uninstalled my app and even cleaned  and reset my emulator still no luck